# curiosity with floating box on camera slideshow

Tags: javascript, css

Could someone explain how is the block "interior blind & courtains", the second one, vertically positioned in this template: https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/55470.html?

I can't find a css top property setted or a margin-top, or something like that, however its position, in my monitor is 493.8px from top.

I feeling like a beginner in css.

Answer (score 1):

The block with `.camera_caption` class is set to `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` in camera.css, which makes it stick to the bottom of it's container.

Comment: I notice the bottom property, but I was thinking that he should have at least a height property on the camera_caption div, for that to work. However, after your post, I realise that there is a padding-bottom in the inner box, streching the camera caption. So he calculated the size of the screen with javascript and setted a value based on the calculation to get the box in a proper position on the screen, right?

Comment: But now, I just don't get why to do that instead of just put a top property.

Comment: @jairhumberto no, it doesn't require height property for that to work.
you can set bottom property to make it stick to bottom, you don't need to know distance from top for that, especially when container height is variable.

Comment: but then, how can you be sure that the box will be positioned at exactly where you want? or even be visible on screen?

Comment: because by setting bottom:0 for an absolutely positioned element, you basically say:
`Set the bottom edge the element to 0px above the bottom edge of its nearest positioned ancestor` - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_bottom)  or try it yourself on simple examples

Comment: just remove the padding-bottom 24% from the right_slider_side sl_1 div and see what I am taking about. If you don't define an height for your box it will be positioned at the bottom, but to make it visible on the viewport he needed to set this padding-bottom property, which in turn streched the parent div, and did the exact same rule of putting an height of 690px in the camera_caption div. just try it and you will see.